# Why do I get a StackOverflowException with my property?

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Please explain to me why this code produces a `StackOverflowException`.

There is a mistake in one of the lines as I have shown using comment. I do not however understand why this gives me a `StackOverflowException`.

```
class TimePeriod
{
    private double seconds;

    public double hour
    {
        get { return hour / 3600; }  // should be :  get { return seconds / 3600; }
        set { seconds = value * 3600; }
    }
}

class Program
{        
    static void Main()
    {
        TimePeriod t = new TimePeriod();
        t.hour = 5;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Time in hours: " + t.hour);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `return hour / 3600` to do, exactly? How do you expect `hour` to be evaluated? (Hint: it calls the property again. Which calls the property. Which calls the property...)

Comment: It appears that your comment solves the problem.  If you were to use the seconds variable instead of `hour` you'd be fine.  How is it you have the solution in your code already?

Comment: @paqogomez I knew how to fix it. I just didn't know why I got the SE exception

Comment: It seems to me that debugging this would have quickly made it obvious why it was failing.

Comment: @Golazo here is a perfect link to read in regards to the `What && How` `Property's work http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_properties.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This produces a stack-overflow, because there is a recursive call on the `hour`, when you try to get it.

Here `t.hour`, you try to get the value of `hour`. This we call the getter, which returns `hour / 3600`. This will call again the `hour` and so on and so forth, until the stack will overflow.

Answer (score 12):

In your `hour` property getter, you are accessing the `hour` property, which creates an infinite loop. Seems like you even have a comment just after the bad code that provides the correct answer.